# Gahp server (failure issues ) exited with status 1 unexpectedly

Tags: centos7, condor, grid-computing

I am working on a web-based tool (named cloudcopasi) which take jobs from a user and submit it to bosco resources (compute nodes). I am using a bosco version (condor 8.8.12) on Linux CentOS 7. The web interface allows a user to add a bosco pool which user can use to submit jobs. However, when I try to submit a job, it fails. I tried to test the pool as well by using the following command:

bosco_cluster --test

It gives me the following GAHP error:

```
…..
Testing bosco submission...Passed!
Submission and log files for this job are in /home/cloudcopasi/bosco/local.bosco/bosco-test/boscotest.LTA07r
Waiting for jobmanager to accept job...Passed
Checking for submission to remote slurm cluster (could take ~30 seconds)...Failed
Showing last 5 lines of logs:
01/06/21 13:34:03 [3800] Gahp Server (pid=3815) exited with status 1 unexpectedly
01/06/21 13:34:08 [3800] gahp server not up yet, delaying ping
01/06/21 13:34:08 [3800] No jobs left, shutting down
01/06/21 13:34:08 [3800] Got SIGTERM. Performing graceful shutdown.
01/06/21 13:34:08 [3800] **** condor_gridmanager (condor_GRIDMANAGER) pid 3800 EXITING WITH STATUS 0
```

I am not sure what I am missing but I don’t understand how to solve this “Gahp server” issue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This a probably an ssh failure (network, authentication, or authorization). Bosco runs the following command to access the remote cluster submit host:

```
<sbin>/remote_gahp <user>@<hostname> batch_gahp
```

You can run it on the command line to get more details about what's going wrong. remote_gahp is a bash script, so you can dig in further, if necessary.

Comment: Hi, I ran the command you said and got the following output:

`Agent pid 14621
/home/FCAM/hbaig/bosco/glite/bin/batch_gahp.symlink: /home/FCAM/hbaig/bosco/glite/bin/../lib/condor/libglobus_common.so.0: no version information available (required by /home/FCAM/hbaig/bosco/glite/bin/batch_gahp.symlink)
$GahpVersion: 1.8.0 Mar 31 2008 INFN\ blahpd\ (poly,new_esc_format) $`

I am able to connect to remote server where bosco is installed and don’t  understand how could it be an SSH issue. 

I am totally a beginner and don't understand how to proceed with it. Thanks for your due help.

Comment: I also tried to monitor the status of submitted jobs and the result are given below that might be helpful for you to figure out what is going on:

`$ condor_q -hold

-- Schedd: <hostname> : <127.0.0.1:11000?... @ 01/07/21 18:01:30
 ID      OWNER          HELD_SINCE  HOLD_REASON
  46.0   hbaig         1/6  13:34  Failed to start GAHP: Agent pid 3832\nImportError: No module named site\nAgent pid 3832 killed\n`